# Функция в javascript

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Только начал изучать javascript и столкнулся с одной проблемой. Хочу по нажатии на кнопку менять нолик на крестик, но из-за чего-то не получается. Не могу понять из-за чего. Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            Function run(){
                var a = document.getElementById("button");
                if(a.value == "0"){
                    a.value = "X";
                } else{
                    a.value = "X";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id = "page">
            <table id="tab" cellpadding="0" border="1" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="1" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="2" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="3" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="4" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="5" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="6" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="7" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="8" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="9" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id = "page">
            <table id="tab" cellpadding="0" border="1" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="1" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="2" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="3" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="4" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="5" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="6" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="7" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="8" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="9" value="0" onClick="run()" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            Function run(){
                    var a = document.getElementById("1");
                    if (a.value == "0") a.value = "X";
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Т.е. теперь я хочу изменить только первую ячейку.

Comment: document.getElementById("button")

Я не вижу ни одного элемента с ID равным button

    if(a.value == "0"){
        a.value = "X";
    } else{
        a.value = "X";
    }

В обоих случаях = "X"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью рабочий пример :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function run (id) {
                var a = document.getElementById(id);
                if (a.value == "0") {
                    a.value = "X";
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div id = "page">
            <table id="tab" cellpadding="0" border="1" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="1" value="0" onclick="run(1)" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="2" value="0" onclick="run(2)" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="3" value="0" onclick="run(3)" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="4" value="0" onclick="run(4)" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="5" value="0" onclick="run(5)" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="6" value="0" onclick="run(6)" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="7" value="0" onclick="run(7)" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="8" value="0" onclick="run(8)" class="b1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="9" value="0" onclick="run(9)" class="b1"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, у вас нет на странице элемента с id button, который вы пытаетесь найти.

Во-вторых, код нужно заключать в такой блок:

```
window.onload = function() {
    /* тут ваш код */
}
```

чтобы он выполнялся после полной загрузки страницы, либо размещать его в самом низу элемента body

В-третьих, у вас неправильно составлено условия в функции, точнее, если вы хотите просто менять значение на X, но не обратно, то блок else вам не нужен.

Comment: @andreyqin, точно, спасибо. А в чем теперь проблема? (новый код добавил в вопрос)

Comment: Код из head убрали?

Comment: @andreyqin, да. И поместил в самый низ body, как Вы сказали. Если что, новый код в вопросе внизу.

Comment: А я где-то читал, что в head лучше скрипты держать... Может, я не понимаю еще что-то, только начал изучать.

Comment: @compl, в обновленном коде у Вас function с большой буквы. А скрипты лучше держать в отдельных файлов и подключать в head с помощью <script src=""></script>. При этом надо быть внимательным, что бы код запускался после того, как страница сформируется, обычно с помощью window.onload = function(){}. Но я думаю, вы до этого чуть позже дойдете в процессе изучения.

Comment: @Alex Krass, спасибо, разобрался!