# Изменение цены в зависимости от select

Tags: javascript

Почему-то в [jsfiddle все работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oLotraa2/112/), а как подключаешь на сайт хром пишет:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at script.js:2

```
<select name="city" id="myselect">
  <option value="111">Котел 1</option>
  <option value="222">Котел 2</option>
  <option value="333">Котел 3</option>
  <option value="444">Котел 3</option>
</select>
<div id="mydiv">600</div>

document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("change", function () {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "Цена: " + this.value;
});
```

Comment: Потому что "на сайте" Ваш код находится выше элемента `"myselect"`.

Comment: Используйте событие построения DOM, чтобы после него точно элемент нашёлся бы: `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @Other не могли бы подробнее расписать?

Comment: `window.onload = function() { [сюда_поместите_ваш_js_код] }`

Comment: Вы конечно спрашиваете другое, но в дубликате ответы на Ваш вопрос

Comment: вопрос с практически такой же проблемой как у Вас https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/366571/191745